# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement while exporting an Oracle database from Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, export

Executing below command from the command line is successful, but executing the same command from a Java class throws an "invalid SQL statement"-error.

```
EXPDP DCR/DCR2017 DIRECTORY=D33 DUMPFILE=DCR.DMP SCHEMAS=DCR
```

Java Code:

```
  String sql ="EXPDP DCR/DCR2017 DIRECTORY=D33 DUMPFILE=DCR.DMP SCHEMAS=DCR";
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl","DCR","DCR2017");
  PreparedStatement prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
  boolean execute = prepareStatement.execute();
  System.out.println(execute);
```

Comment: `expdp` is a command-line tool, as you already know as you said that was sucessful. It is not a SQL command. Hence the error you get. You would see the same thing trying to do that from, say, a SQL\*Plus prompt. There is PL/SQL package access to data pump, but do you really want to do it that way, or from Java from a system command? Why not just do it from the command line?

Comment: yes, expdp is a command line statement. then what should be the SQL statement For this. As I want to control the export and import From Java that's why I am trying to use it from Java

Comment: There isn't a single SQL statement, but you could [work with the API if you really wanted to](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_api.htm#SUTIL977).  Or you can call `expdp` via `getRuntime().exec()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call expdp from SQL. It's a command-line function. There is a PL/SQL API for that called [`dbms_datapump`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_datpmp.htm), which you can call from PL/SQL.